# PHP - Calculate the required memory to overwrite the memory limit

Tags: php, memory, limit

I need to upload a big image file so I need to temporary edit the PHP's ini `memory_limit` to prevent the `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted`. To be clear, this change needs to be temporary and I do not want to set the limit to -1, which means unlimited memory.

I calculate the needed amount of memory in bytes and compares it to the current PHP ini's memory limit in bytes. Despite the needed memory does **not** exceeds the current PHP's ini's memory_limit, I still got the earlier mentioned fatal error. My question is why I still get the fatal error despite there is enough memory available to output the image?

```
// How much (extra) memory we need to load the image can be calculated by:
// ((image WIDTH * image HEIGHT) * BITS PER PIXEL = 4) / 1048576 bytes(1 MB)
// Source of this formula: https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/allocate-memory-on-the-fly-PHP-image-resizing/

$img             = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['tmp_name']);
$info            = getimagesize($_FILES['tmp_name']);

$memoryLimit     = ini_get('memory_limit'); // 128M
$oldMemoryLimit  = (float)rtrim($memoryLimit, 'M'); // 128  
$newMemoryLimit  = (float)ceil((($info[0]*$info[1])*4)/1048576); // 40

if ($oldMemoryLimit != 0 && (memory_get_usage()+$newMemoryLimit) >  $oldMemoryLimit)
{
    ini_set('memory_limit', $oldMemoryLimit+$newMemoryLimit.'M');
}

ob_start();
imagepng($img, null); // Fatal error: Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted
$image = ob_get_clean();

ini_set('memory_limit', $memoryLimit);
```

The expected result is that it should increase the PHP ini's memory_limit when the needed memory used by the `imagepng` exceeds the current memory_limit. In other words: The PHP script should allocate enough memory to succesfully output the uploaded image by the imagepng function.

Comment: What's the point of counting all this when you can just set -1 and forget.

Comment: Just an idea. Have you consider uploading this large file in chunks?

Comment: I did, but I prefer to not to do it with chunks, nor setting the limit to -1.

Comment: So what’s the point in not setting -1? I mean I could upload a ridiculously large image and your script will still fail because your instance will run out of physical RAM. Because, even though you don’t set -1, you still allow an infinite amount of RAM to be allocated, which is basically same as disabling the limit in the first place.